# Pycharm displays only a part of the output

Tags: python-3.x, graph, pycharm

I am new to python. I started to use pycharm to create embeddings for a large graph. However, the embedding in pycharm's 'run' does not get displayed completely. Its being diplayed as:

> [[-0.0245612   0.02678017]  [-0.03880838  0.00622786]  [-0.05384697 
>   0.1101577 ]  ...,   [ 0.00589567 -0.01192585]  [-0.00726813  0.00367316]  [-0.00884804  0.00646897]]

I tried to write the output in a different file, but it's still the same. Is there a way to expand the output to get the full embedding?

Comment: Are you sure this is a PyCharm problem? What does your code do?

Comment: It basically forms embeddings for graph, I have increased the output buffer limit in pycharm too. With small graphs, I do get the embeddigns, but its some how does not scale to large graphs.

Comment: And if you write it to a file from your code it does the same? I don't mean, safe PyCharms output, but write to a file directly from your Python Code.

Comment: Yes I did that! Its still the same.